# AVAudioPlayer on OS X not playing any sound

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to play a sound using `AVAudioPlayer` on os x (not iOS!). I'm using the following code:

```
AVAudioPlayer *player;
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
          soundFileURL error:&err];

if( err ){
    NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
}
else{
    player.delegate = self;
    player.numberOfLoops = -1;
    player.currentTime = 0;
    player.volume = 1.0;
    [player play];
}
```

All is ok, and the player calls play function without the errors. However I can't hear any sound after that. I'm sure that my audio file is ok, because I was able to play it using `NSSound` class. The reason I want to use `AVAudioPlayer` is that when I'm using `NSSound` class and I play it in a loop there is short pause in between and that's why I wanted to try `AVAudioPlayer`.

Comment: Define the *player as property so it gets not evaporated after your method finsishes?

Comment: Thanks, a lot. That was it - if you'll write your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `*player` as a `property` so it gets not evaporated after your method finishes.